# Spring sessionid in request body xml instead of JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: spring, spring-security

Most of my Spring application uses regular spring security. However, there is a (non-negotiable) requirement for certain pages to be accessed by an embedded system that communicates exclusively via XML inside a POST body. That is to say, it's not capable of passing 'JSESSIONID=xxx' or receiving cookies, but instead it expects to receive a sessionid via xml on login, which it then repeats back in future requests.

So, on login (I've simplified here), it sends

```
<username>user</username><password>password</password>
```

in a post body to http://example.com/xml_login and expects

```
<sessionid>xxxxxx</sessionid>
```

in reponse. Then all subsequent requests will repeat back the `<sessionid>` tag's contents as part of its body.

Any ideas how to go about getting spring security to use this?

My first attempt was to try writing a filter to extract the sessionid and crowbar a JSESSION= into the body, but it turned out to be too late (by the time I had a request object to get the body from, spring security had already established the session, and I can't see any way of doing anything like 'request.setSession(id)'). The only other thing I can think of is to write my own session handling outside of spring security, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to do that.

thanks

Comment: Why you can't reuse session id of the session created by Spring Security?

Comment: Ah, there's a thought - I could use spring security's sessionid for the initial handshake, configure it to not create new sessions for requests to pages that aren't the login page, and have all my other controllers set the user manually based on its sessionid entry in the database. The only downside is I still wouldn't be able to use session variables, unless anyone knows a way I can grab the session variables of a session by id...?